# I changed my Blogger to my own domain, and now my OpenID doesn't work anymore.

Tags: support, openid

I switched my blog on Blogger to use my own domain name. It didn't occur to me that this would invalidate my old OpenID, preventing me from logging in anymore. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with Blogger's implementation of OpenID. Try this:

1. Log into Blogger in a separate tab.
2. Come back and log into Stack Overflow.
3. The credentials should be cached, so instead of sending you to the login page, you'll be logged right in.